# dplyr 0.7 equivalent for deprecated mutate_

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

I cannot find in `dplyr 0.7` a way to replace the *mutate_* function which is going to be deprecated.

The *mutate_* function is useful in my use case : I store in a database (string format) many instructions (that can be filtered if needed) and apply these instructions to one or several data frames.

For example :

```
dplyr::tibble(test = "test@test") %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_(.dots = list("test2" = "substr(test, 1, 5)",
                              "test3" = "substr(test, 5, 5)"))
```

Is there a way to do this with dplyr 0.7 keeping variables and instructions as character?

Comment: The doc `?mutate_` states "dplyr now uses tidy evaluation semantics", referring to the rlang package which has a vignette on "tidy evaluation". Good luck if you go down that road.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To expand a little bit on [MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick)'s example, let's assume you have a number of instructions stored as strings, as well as the corresponding names that you want to assign to the resulting computations:

```
ln <- list( "test2", "test3" )
lf <- list( "substr(test, 1, 5)", "substr(test, 5, 5)" )
```

Match up names to their instructions and convert everything to quosures:

```
ll <- setNames( lf, ln ) %>% lapply( rlang::parse_quosure )
```

As per [aosmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2461552/aosmith)'s suggestion, the entire list can now be passed to mutate, using the special `!!!` operator:

```
tibble( test = "test@test" ) %>% mutate( !!! ll )
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#        test test2 test3
#       <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 test@test test@     @
```

Comment: You could also do `mutate(X, !!! ll)` instead of the whole `do.call` step.

Comment: Great idea, aosmith. I'll update the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks very much MrFlick, Artem and aosmith !

Answer (score 5):

Here's one alternative

```
a <- "test2"
b <- "test3"
dplyr::tibble(test = "test@test") %>% 
dplyr::mutate(a := !!rlang::parse_expr("substr(test, 1, 5)"),
  b := !!rlang::parse_expr("substr(test, 5, 5)"))
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#        test     a     b
#       <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 test@test test@     @
```

We use the `:=` operator to dynamically name parameters with strings, and we parse the expression string for the transformation and unwrap it with `!!`

Comment: @TylerRinker I updated to `parse_expr()` which isn't deprecated and doesn't require the environment to be specified since we're really not using it.