# Using mutate_each to scale and center variables in sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, dplyr, data-science, sparklyr

I'm working on a clustering problem in `sparklyr`. Many of the variables in the training set are measured on different scales and thus differ by orders of magnitude. Per best practice I am trying to scale and center the data.

There are a number of different formulas to do this, the most traditional being (X - µ) / σ where X is the random variable , µ= mean, and σ= standard deviation. I tend like to also use (X - x) / (x_max  - x_min) where X= random variable, x=sample mean, x_max= maximum value, and x_min =minimum value.

I am getting a wierd result after applying this transformation using `dplyr`. Consider this example:

```
    #connect to spark
    library(sparklyr)
    library(SparkR)
    library(dplyr)
    sc = spark_connect(master = 'yarn-client',
                       spark_home = '/usr/hdp/current/spark-client',
                       app_name = 'sparklyr'
                       # config = list(
                       #   "sparklyr.shell.executor-memory" = "XG",
                       #   "sparklyr.shell.driver-memory"   = "XG",
                       #   "spark.driver.maxResultSize"     = "XG" # may need to transfer a lot of data into R 
    )

    sparkR.init()

#create a dataframe where variables in the dataset differ by an order of magnitude
mat <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = rnorm(200, mean=100,sd=10), nrow = 1000, ncol = 50))
mat1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(data = rnorm(200, mean=0,sd=1), nrow = 1000, ncol = 50))
colnames(mat1) <- paste('X',1:50,sep='')
mat.final <- cbind(mat,mat1)

#copy to Spark
dat.out <- sdf_copy_to(sc,mat.final,'dat',overwrite=TRUE)

#define centering and scaling function
scale.center <- function(x){
  (x-mean(x,na.rm=TRUE)) /(max(x,na.rm = TRUE)-min(x,na.rm = TRUE))
}

#scale data
dat.out1 <- 
  dat.out %>%
  mutate_each(funs(s=scale.center))
```

The code runs , but I get something strange:

```
str(dat.out1)

$ ops:List of 4
  ..$ name: chr "mutate"
  ..$ x   :List of 4
  .. ..$ name: chr "mutate"
  .. ..$ x   :List of 4
  .. .. ..$ name: chr "mutate"
  .. .. ..$ x   :List of 4
  .. .. .. ..$ name: chr "mutate"
  .. .. .. ..$ x   :List of 4
  .. .. .. .. ..$ name: chr "mutate"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ x   :List of 4
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ name: chr "mutate"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ x   :List of 4
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ name: chr "mutate"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ x   :List of 4
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ name: chr "mutate"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ x   :List of 4
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ name: chr "mutate"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ x   :List of 4
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ name: chr "mutate"
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ x   :List of 4
  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..$ name: chr "mutate"
  .. ..
```

The above is just a portion of the output after running `str`. Thoughts on what's going wrong here. I'm surprised there isn't a build in function for centering and scaling.

Comment: `?scale` ships with base R

Comment: I don't think that's implemented in SparkR.

Comment: Oh right sorry, so `scale` produces an error in your code above? Isn't `mutate_each` deprecated in favour of `mutate_all`, I wonder if that has anything to do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Thoughts on what's going wrong here.

It is essentially the same problem as described in [Sparklyr: how to center a Spark table based on column?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43614220/6910411) - aggregation functions used in `mutate` are expanded to global (without `PARTITION BY` clause) window functions making this approach completely useless in practice.

> I'm surprised there isn't a build in function for centering and scaling.

Well, in general Spark operates using ML `Transformers`, a bunch of which, has been ported to `sparklyr`. These can be distinguished by `ft_` prefix. Unfortunately [`StandardScaler`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#standardscaler) and [`MinMaxScaler`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#minmaxscaler) are not ported yet. It is not that hard to implement your own interface though.

If you want a quick that can work on the data as-is:

```
library(rlang)
library(glue)

# Compute all the stats at once
stats <- dat.out %>% summarise_all(funs(avg, min, max)) %>% collect()

# Separate stats into components
cols <- dat.out %>% colnames()
avgs <- stats %>% select(ends_with("avg")) %>% unlist
mins <- stats %>% select(ends_with("min")) %>% unlist
maxs <- stats %>% select(ends_with("max")) %>% unlist

# Create expressions
exprs <- glue("({cols} - {avgs}) / ({maxs} - {mins})") %>% 
  setNames(cols) %>%
  lapply(parse_quosure)

dat.out %>% mutate(!!! exprs)
```

Credits once again go to [Artem Sokolov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300187/artem-sokolov) ([dplyr 0.7 equivalent for deprecated mutate_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45360858/6910411)).

**Note**:

Don't use `.` with functions which are to be used with `sparklyr`. `dplyr` will try to match these as database functions in a "prefix" database and fail or produce unintended results.

Comment: The only issue I'm having with this solution is that it doesn't appear to scale well. My **actual** data has 500 columns and 12 million rows. `stats <- dat.out %>% summarise_all(funs(avg, min, max)) %>% collect()` has already been running for over 5 minutes.

Comment: By 5 minutes I mean 1 hour :/

Comment: The data is in a hive table. My configuration for connecting to Spark R is `sc = spark_connect(master = 'yarn-client',
                   spark_home = '/usr/hdp/current/spark-client',
                   app_name = 'sparklyr',
                    config = list(
                      "sparklyr.shell.executor-memory" = "24G",
                   "sparklyr.shell.driver-memory"   = "16G",
                   "spark.driver.maxResultSize"     = "16G") 
)

sparkR.init()`  I'm reading the data from hive using the dplyr function `tbl`

Comment: And I'm actually only reading in 1/12 of the table, that is, 1 million rows instead of 12 million